# Parent field missing from new CloudKit dashboard metadata?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckrecord

I'm looking at the new style CloudKit dashboard and i'm unable to see the parent field for the ckrecords in my database - i'm specifically looking for the parent field as i'm working on sharing and need to test if the parent field is being correctly set. The old style dashboard showed it clearly alongside the other metadata... Can anyone help please?